# Posting php multi dimentional array into a new window

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, post

I have an associative array I got from my database.

I would like to open a new window with that associated array posted to it.

I did manage to post it in ajax post, But it's not what I need because I want a new window!

Using a form is impossible because you cannot put that kind of data in an hidden input.

So how do I do it?

Comment: PHP can't open new windows in your browser. You might want to use JavaScript for this (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: Put your array in a session, use it on the second page then unset it, if you don't need it anymore. And as @AmalMurali php won't open a new window, you should use js

Comment: AS you said you managed to post it in ajax post, now on success use jquery to open up a new window and echo it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used session as suggested by @CodeBird.

```
$_SESSION['temp_info'] = $array;
```

Then I just `<a href>` to another page.

Where I used the following code:

```
$array = $_SESSION['temp_info'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Php example:

```
echo json_encode( array('int'=>123, 'char'=>'abc', 'array'=>array(1,2,3)) );
```

The javascript:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.php", function( data ) {
    console.log( data ); // data is a json-object
    data.each(function(item){
        console.log( typeof item.int ) // Number, value 123
        console.log( typeof item.char ) // String, value '123'
        console.log( typeof item.array ) // array/object, values 1,2,3
    });
});
```

***edit**: the names `int, char and array` are choosen as example. One might want to avoid the usage of reserved names as variable names*

*edit: misread, changed to better answer*